# How to convert limit conditions?

Tags: limits, proof-writing, limits-without-lhopital

I was doing an exercise in limits and I was working with the following limit:

$$\lim_{y\to\infty}{y\sin{\frac{1}{y}}}$$

I understand that I’m meant to use the identity

$$\lim_{x\to 0}{\frac{\sin{x}}{x}}=1$$

to reduce this somehow, and so I reasoned that I could take $y=x^{-1}$ and get

$$\lim_{x^{-1}\to\infty}{\frac{\sin{x}}{x}}$$

I’m almost there, but I’m not sure how to convert the conditions of the limit. I know that $x^{-1}\to\infty \iff x \to 0$, but am I allowed to simply make the jump and say

$$\lim_{x^{-1}\to\infty}{\frac{\sin{x}}{x}} =\lim_{x\to0}{\frac{\sin{x}}{x}}$$

just like that? Is there a theorem or axiom or definition that vindicates this step?

Comment: There is theorem for limit of composition for functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me bring one theorem from Kudriavtsev L.D. "Course of Mathematical Analysis",  4.8*, 1 tom. 1981, page 108 (I couldn't find the answer I posted before, probably deleted).

Assume exists **finite or infinite** limits $\lim\limits_{x\to a}f(x)=b$ and $\lim\limits_{y\to b}F(y)$. Also let's assume, that exists some deleted neighborhood of $a$ in which holds $f(x)\ne b$. Then exists limit of compound function $F\circ f$ and holds

$$\lim\limits_{x\to a}F(f(x))=\lim\limits_{y\to b}F(y)$$

In your case $F(y) = y\sin\frac{1}{y}$ and $y=f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$. I hope it will not be difficult for you to check the conditions of application.